# Python: machine learning without imputing missing data

Tags: python, machine-learning, pca, missing-data

I am currently working with a quite particular dataset : it has about 1000 columns and 1M rows, but about 90% of the values are Nan. 
This is not because the records are bad, but because the data represent measurement made on individuals and only about 100 features are relevant for each individual. As such, imputing missing values would completely destroy the information in the data.

It is not  easy either to just group together individuals that have the same features and only consider the column relevant to each subgroup, as this would actually yield extremely small groups for each set of columns (almost any combination of filled in columns is possible for a given individual).

The issue is, scikit learn dimension reduction methods cannot handle missing values. Is there a package that does, or should I use a different method and skip dimension reduction? 
I

Comment: I could be wrong, but this question - although good - probably doesn't belong on SO.

Comment: What do you want to do at the end of the day? If you just want to do some sort of clustering / community detection, you could think about your data as a bipartite graph and determine the modules in the graph.

Comment: PCA is actually meant for such kind of data-sets. I suggest you give it a try. Replace missing values with zeros and apply PCA on the resulting data-set.

Comment: Sorry, but that is a terrible idea. A NaN is not a zero. If you really have to put a value, you should either try to interpolate the data in the high dimensional space it lives in (which is not really an option here as the valid entries appear to be few and far between) or you should use some measure of the central tendency in that dimension (mean, median); both of these are not ideal as a preprocessing step for PCA as you are bound to underestimate the variance in any particular direction (which is what PCA is all about), but they are the best you can do if you really need to know the PCs.

Comment: You mention that only 100 features are relevant, why can't you just filter the 100 features for every data instance? You clearly have to identify the features - or if you don't know what your features are you should probably look into neural networks as they can automatically identify which features represent your data through iterations (epochs). Bottom line, bad data or bad features is your arch nemesis in any machine learning problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use gradient boosting packages which handle missing values and are ideal for your case.Since you asked for packages gbm in R and xgboost in python can be used.If you want to know how missing values are handled automatically in xgboost go through section 3.4 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.02754v3.pdf) to get an insight.

Comment: Please upvote the answer too if you are accepting it!Thanks!